# MYSQL IN clause not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have used the IN clause but the result is showing blank,for testing i have used

```
       category='computer'
```

and it works but when i use it with IN clause the result is blank

```
<body>
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error()); 


$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM information WHERE title LIKE '%test%' AND category  IN ( computer, school, Hotel)");  

  //And we display the results 
 while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 echo $result['id'];
 echo $result['title'];
 echo"</br>";
  } ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

Your forgot the quotes in

```
IN ( computer, school, Hotel)
```

Instead use

```
IN ( 'computer', 'school', 'Hotel')
```

Answer (score 0):

You've missed the single quotes around your string values in the list:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM information 
                     WHERE title LIKE '%test%' 
                     AND category  IN ( 'computer', 'school', 'Hotel')");
```

Answer (score 0):

computer, school, Hotel should be inside simple coastes as this ('computer', 'school', 'Hotel')